# How can I change font size of PHP variable?

Tags: php, html

```
$var=5;
echo $var;
```

I want that the output which is 5 is display bigger in size. I mean how can I resize its output? Maybe it's a silly question, but I'm a beginner, so. :)

Comment: PHP doesn't know anything about font sizes. You change a font size by some method of your output system. If you're outputting to a browser use HTML and CSS

Comment: echo "<p>consider some CSS styling of $var perhaps?</p>"

Comment: i used font it works ! ..any other u know then tell me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let suppose that you are using PHP to render web page.

The one of the ways is to use `p` or `div` or `span` tag with appropriate styling (`font-size` in your case). For example,

```
echo '<span style="font-size: 32pt">' . $var . '</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **CSS** if you render a web page. Search for `font-size` on the internet.

Here a possible solution:

`<span style="font-size: 200%"><?php $var = 5; echo $var; ?></span>`

Comment: <span style="font-size:10px;"><?php echo $var; ?></span>